# How do I select all the timing together with the name of the point at which the time occurs from a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, selection

This is a section of the dictionary:

```
{'WayPoint46_WayPoint39': [(14.547985, datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 23, 18, 45, 47), True)], 'WayPoint39_WayPoint38': [(7.208904, datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 23, 18, 46, 13), True)], ... }
```

I want to select for example, `WayPoint46_WayPoint39, 14.547985.`

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: ``dict_['WayPoint46_WayPoint39'][0][0]``, where ``dict_`` is the input dict ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simpliest solution:

```
for key, value in input_dict.items():
    print(key, value[0][0])
```

With input_dict equal to your input, the output looks like:

```
WayPoint46_WayPoint39 14.547985
WayPoint39_WayPoint38 7.208904
```

For sum you can use sum() function:

```
print(sum([value[0][0] for value in input_dict.values()]))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked! Also if i now have to add all the times, how would i do that?

Comment: Added example to the answer